Show that $\frac{1-xy-x}{x+y+3} + \frac{1-zy-y}{z+y+3}+ \frac{1-xz-z}{x+z+3} \geq \frac{5}{11}$
The problem
a) Show that $\frac{ab}{a+b}+ \frac{cd}{c+d} \leq \frac{(a+c)(b+d)}{a+b+c+d}$, with equality for $ad=bc$ (solved already)
b) Let the real numbers $x,y,z \in (0, \infty)$ with $x+y+z=1$. Show that
$\frac{1-xy-x}{x+y+3} + \frac{1-zy-y}{z+y+3}+ \frac{1-xz-z}{x+z+3} \geq \frac{5}{11}$
my idea
For point a) I thought of the inequality between harmonic mean and algebraic mean that gives us the inequality
$\frac{ab}{a+b} \leq \frac{a+b}{4}=> \frac{ab}{a+b}+ \frac{cd}{c+d} \leq \frac{a+b+c+d}{4}$
Then we have to demonstrate that $ \frac{a+b+c+d}{4} \leq \frac{(a+c)(b+d)}{a+b+c+d}$
Sadly by harmonic and algebric mean I got again that $$ \frac{a+b+c+d}{4} \geq \frac{(a+c)(b+d)}{a+b+c+d}$$ which is not what we need
I don't know what to do forward...I don't think that opening all the parenthesis might help a lot.
Also, point a) might help solve point b), because they are in the same problem.
edit:
Even though point a) is solved in another problem, point b) remains and I wont delet point a) because it might help in solving the problem
Hope one of you can help me! Thank you!

Is it helpful that the LHS is $(a^{-1}+b^{-1})^{-1} + (c^{-1}+d^{-1})^{-1}$?

@preferred_anon I dont think so...all of this gets me to think about harmonic mean or CBS

This question is similar to: Show that if a,b,c,d are positive then $\frac{ab}{a+b}+\frac{cd}{c+d}\le \frac{(a+c)(b+d)}{a+b+c+d}$. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@Gonçalo I edited my question. Thanks for the solution for point a)!

Let $$A:=\frac{1-xy-x}{4-z} + \frac{1-zy-y}{4-x}+ \frac{1-xz-z}{4-y} $$
we have to prove $A\geq \frac{5}{11}$
Now for $0\leq x\leq 1$ we have $${1 \over4-x}\geq {9\over 121}x +{30\over 121}$$
Then $$ A\geq {9\over 121}(x+y+z-3xyz-xy-yz-xz) + {30\over 121}(3-xy-yz-zx -x-y-z)=:B$$
Since $$xy+yz+zx\leq (x+y+z)^2/3 =1/3$$ and $$xyz\leq ({x+y+z\over 3})^3 = 1/27$$
we have $$B\geq {9\over 121}(1-1/9-1/3) + {30\over 121}(3-1/3 -1)={5\over 121}+ {50\over 121}={5\over 11}$$
